# selectfield with added Jquery options, how to save the selected option

Tags: jquery, select, dropdown

I have a selectfield with jquery options for years.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var thisYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
  var startYear = 1960;
  var x;
  for (x = thisYear; x >= startYear; x--) {
    $("#property_build").append("<option value='" + x + "'>" + x + "</option>")
  };
});
```

Selecting this works fine but i don't know how to save this to the db. when i try to save no option is selected.

i tried something like this

```
$('#property_build').on('change', function(e) {

  var optionSelected = $("option:selected");
  var valueSelected = this.value;

  $('#property_build option:selected').val(valueSelected)

});
```

but this is obviously not working. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you just asking how to get the value of a form element in jQuery?  Or something else?  It's not clear to me what you mean by "bind and save" in this case.

Comment: i want to get a selected option so i can save that to the db.  now when i try to save, the no option is saved. ( i edited my question)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be overthinking it.  To get the selected value (or values array for a multi-select) in jQuery, just use `val()` on the `<select>` element:

```
let selectedValue = $('#property_build').val();
```

Comment: how do i connect that again to the selectfield? so i can save it to the db.

Comment: @missbluebell: It's not clear what you mean by "connect that again".  Nor is it clear how any of this relates to a database.  Please elaborate.

Comment: okay. so i have a select field, in which the options are extended with jquery. However when i want to save a new selected option, it doesn't get saved to the db. i made a small test and a html optionfield does get saved. just not the extended jquery options fields. see my codepen as example https://codepen.io/ariellbell/pen/xezZzp
So i am looking for a way to get also the extended jquery option fields to be saved to db.

Comment: @missbluebell: There's currently nothing preventing that from happening.  See an updated version of your own code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BEVKNo  The only change is that I added a `change` handler to the `<select>` element and output the value.  Select any value and you'll see it's captured.  Whatever trouble you're having saving data to a database, the problem is not in the code you're showing or the question you're asking.  This line of code is exactly how you get a value from a `<select>` element in jQuery.

Comment: i see your point. i thought first my code was not complete. but doing some extra research after your answer it has to do how symfony framework works. apparently it sees those extra jquery values as empty or so. Unless you are familiar with that framework the anwser i am looking is not ment in my original question. It's good to know my jquery code itself works fine. its just not ready for symfony.